# Run jquery function using multiple listeners

Tags: jquery

I have a script:

```
 $('#subButton').click( function (){
  // do function stuff
  });
```

I would like to be able to have 2 listeners run the same function.  How can i do that without having all the 'do function stuff' written twice, it is alot of stuff to do.  The listener is click in one instance, and change in the other...

basically i want to do something like this in layman's terms:

```
 $('#subButton').click OR $('#search').change ( function (){
 // do function stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function and use it whenever you want:

```
var fn = function (){
   //do function stuff
};

$('#subButton').click(fn);
$('#search').change(fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the selectors using a comma.

```
  $('#subButton, #search').click(function (){
             // do function stuff
   });
```

Based on your update. You can write your handler in a separate function and give the same function reference for both of them.

```
   function handler(){
       // do function stuff
   } 

   //...

   $('#subButton').click(handler);
   $('#search').change(handler);
```

Comment: sorry @PSL,  edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the handler as a separate function and then use the handler reference to register both the handlers

```
function handler(){
}

$('#subButton').click (handler);
$('#search').change (handler);
```

Comment: sorry Arun,  edited my question.